# Neo4j match array value with node property

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher, node-neo4j

I am trying with this query

```
MATCH(u:User) WHERE ANY(name IN ['ACB','xYz'] WHERE u.first_name =~ "(?i).*name.*") RETURN u
```

it is considering `(?i).*name.*` as static text instead of dynamic value from `name IN ['ACB','xYz']`.

Comment: yes, regex are static text.
But in your example, I think you can add  "['ACB','xYz']" directly in the regex, it's not dynamic here, right ?

Comment: @logisima it is also dynamic. coming in request. Right now just to let the work done I have traversed the whole array and added regex with each element 
**ex.    search_param = search_param.map(function (ele) {
      return '.*(?i)' + ele + '.*'
    });**
but I dont want to traverse the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assemble a regex expression using string concatenation. This case however needs some `toString` hinting:

```
MATCH(u:User) WHERE ANY(name IN ['ACB','xYz'] 
    WHERE u.first_name =~ toString("(?i).*" +name +".*")) 
RETURN u
```